# How do I let Python know that these two words are the same?

Tags: python

I have a `.csv` file. Here is an example:

Table format:

| A | AA |
| --- | --- |
| BB | B |
| C | CC |
| D D | D DD |

Text format:

```
A,AA
BB,B
C,CC
D D,D DD
```

I want Python to know that `A` is equal to `AA`, `BB` is equal to `B`, and `C` is equal to `CC`. Also, the fourth example has spaces.

It can also be reversed, such as checking whether `AA` is equal to `A`.

What I'm working on is a search engine. A word may be written in two ways, so I need to do this.

For example, I have a boolean variable that checks if the search result is `A` and it returns `AA`, then it is `True`. Of course, returning `A` is also `True`.

My code:

```py
query = … // "AA"

result_list = … // ["A"]

sorted_list = [element for element in result_list if element.find(query) != -1]
```

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

How do I let Python know that these two words are the same?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One way to handle this scenario is to use a dictionary that maps words to their equivalent words. For example:

```
word_map = {
    "A": "AA",
    "AA": "A",
    "BB": "B",
    "B": "BB",
    "C": "CC",
    "CC": "C",
    "D D": "D DD",
    "D DD": "D D",
}
```

Then, you can use this dictionary to check if the query is equivalent to any of the elements in the result_list:

```
equivalent_word = word_map.get(query, None)
if equivalent_word in result_list:
    sorted_list.append(equivalent_word)
```

You can add all the equivalent words to the word_map dictionary, and then use this dictionary to check if a word is equivalent to another word.

Comment: Given there are simple and straightforward rules on word "matching", compiling dictionary like that is a waste of time and effort.

Comment: What is even worse, your dict has two pairs of key/value for two words.  To compare three "words" (e.g., "A", "AA", "A A"), you'll need six key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that with a simplified string at the left and right sides. For example, `A` will be simplified as `A`, `AA` be `A`, `D D` as `D`, etc. Try this :

```
import pandas as pd

def simplify(s):
  return "".join(set(s))

# data.csv
# A,AA
# BB,B
# C,CC
# D D,D DD

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)
df = df.values.tolist()
result = []
for i in df:
  result.append(simplify(i[0]) == simplify(i[1]))
print(result)
```

The output must be like this :

```
[True, True, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn both strings into sets, add a space to one, and check if they match.  Wrap that into function and use as you will:

```
def isequal_with_spaces(s1, s2):
    set1 = set(s1 + " ")
    return set1.issuperset(s2)


assert isequal_with_spaces('A', 'AA')
assert not isequal_with_spaces('A', 'BA')
assert isequal_with_spaces('A', 'A A')
assert isequal_with_spaces('AA', 'AAA A ')
assert not isequal_with_spaces('B', 'A A')
```

This doesn't take into account case and might work not quite as you need for strings like `'AB' == 'A A'`, but that wasn't specified in the question =)

---

Moreover, if a *"word"* could be defined as *"capital letter followed by any number of spaces or the same letters"*, and that's guaranteed, you can simplify `isequal_with_spaces` even further:

```
def isequal_with_spaces(s1, s2):
   return s1[0] == s2[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

After using `csv` module to read the rows as lists, remove any spaces, and compare the characters:

ex: `all(set(x.replace(' ', '')) == set(A[0]) for x in A)`

```
>>> A = ['AA']
>>> D = ['D','D DD']
>>> all(set(x.replace(' ', '')) == set(A[0]) for x in A)
True
>>> all(set(x.replace(' ', '')) == set(D[0]) for x in D)
True
```

Answer (score -3):

Maybe it helps if you check for the hex code. Something like this:

```py
input = "A AA"
hex_code=(":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(x)) for x in input))

if "41" in hex_code:
    print("True")
```

Comment: Your answer is invalid

Comment: Isn't it just a super-complicated way of checking if a string contains `'A'`?